# How do I use jQuery to disable a textarea + Submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

After a user submits a comment, I want the textarea and summit button to be "disabled" and somewhat visually disabled.

Like Youtube.

How can I do that with Jquery using the simplest plugin and/or method?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simply set the `disabled` attribute on your input elements when the button is clicked:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
   $("#mytext,#mybutton").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/JcXjG/

Comment: Or you can do `.attr("disabled", true)` and `.attr("disabled", false)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#idOfbutton').click(function() {
        $('#idOfTextarea').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#idOfbutton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
});
```

This basically says: When the document is "ready", attach an event handler to the button's (HTML ID "idOfButton") click event which will set the `disabled` attribute of the textarea (HTML ID "idOfTextarea") and the button.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('form').submit(function(){
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $(this, '#textarea').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So first handle the event where the user submits the comment and then disable the textarea and submit button. (assuming your submit button can be selected with "input#submit-comment" and your textarea can be selected with "textarea". The addClass part is optional but can be used for you to style those elements differently if they happen to be disabled.

```
$("input#submit-comment").click(function(){
     $("textarea").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
     $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
     // ... Actually submit comment here, assuming you're using ajax
     return false;
}
```